# Ruby find where before updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to search for results where the updated_at on one result is after the created at of another this is my code in a short and sweet version

i am getting a syntax error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "13"
LINE 1: ...ERE ((group_id = 14 and created_at >=  2016-08-04 13:39:35 U...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "chats".* FROM "chats" WHERE ((group_id = 14 and created_at >=  2016-08-04 13:39:35 UTC))  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

but i do not understand why is it something to do with the time?

```
@grouparchived = @groupread.updated_at

filter1 = "(group_id = "+@arandomthing.to_s + " and created_at >= "+@grouparchived.to_s+")"

@chats1 = Chat.where(@filter1).order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Chat.where(group_id: @arandomthing).where('created_at >= ?', @groupread.updated_at).order('created_at DESC')
```

Concating strings like you're doing is a recipe for disaster, much better to use the tools Rails gives you.